# Find value in an array

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, how can I find a value in an array?

Comment: To everyone who complains about this sort of question: please read the FAQ: 'No question is too trivial or too "newbie"'. If you don't like the question, don't answer it, and let someone else do so. If the question has already been asked and answered on SO, then sure, mark it as a duplicate. But there's no reason to berate the newcomers for being new.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

If you're trying to determine whether a certain value exists inside an array, you can use [Array#include?(value)](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.include?(3)   # => true
a.include?(9)   # => false
```

If you mean something else, check the [Ruby Array API](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html)

Comment: I would use Array#index, but checking the Ruby Array API is a great tip.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 127):

Using `Array#select` will give you an array of elements that meet the criteria. But if you're looking for a way of getting the element out of the array that meets your criteria, `Enumerable#detect` would be a better way to go:

```
array = [1,2,3]
found = array.select {|e| e == 3} #=> [3]
found = array.detect {|e| e == 3} #=> 3
```

Otherwise you'd have to do something awkward like:

```
found = array.select {|e| e == 3}.first
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew about `Enumerable#select` but `#detect` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: `array.select{}` will go through all elements in the array looking those which match the condition.
`array.find` instead will return the first element that match the condition. So preferable use `array.find{ |e| e == 3 }` then `array.select{ |e| e == 3 }.first`

Comment: I think you meant `.find_index`  I don't know if there is any `.find`

Comment: `Enumerable#find` is apparently an alias for `Enumerable#detect`

Answer (score 58):

If you want find **one** value from the Array, use [`Array#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
arr = [1,2,6,4,9] 
arr.find {|e| e % 3 == 0}   #=>  6
```

If you want to find **multiple** values from the Array, use [`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select):

```
arr.select {|e| e % 3 == 0} #=> [ 6, 9 ]
e.include? 6              #=> true
```

To find if a value exists in an Array you can also use [`#in?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-in-3F) when using ActiveSupport. `#in?` works for any object that responds to `#include?`:

```
arr = [1, 6]
6.in? arr                 #=> true
```

Comment: I can't see any `Array#find` in the Ruby references.  Must be a Rails thing since other people have mentioned it.   Hmmm....

Comment: @Ross Attrill No, It's in `Enumerable`,  https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find

Comment: I incorrectly assumed that ruby-doc shows included and inherited methods.  Important lesson for me.

Answer (score 24):

you can use [Array.select](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) or [Array.index](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index) to do that.

Answer (score 24):

Like this?

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ]
a[2] +  a[0] + a[1]    #=> "cab"
a[6]                   #=> nil
a[1, 2]                #=> [ "b", "c" ]
a[1..3]                #=> [ "b", "c", "d" ]
a[4..7]                #=> [ "e" ]
a[6..10]               #=> nil
a[-3, 3]               #=> [ "c", "d", "e" ]
# special cases
a[5]                   #=> nil
a[5, 1]                #=> []
a[5..10]               #=> []
```

or like this?

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
a.index("b")   #=> 1
a.index("z")   #=> nil
```

[See the manual](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html).

Answer (score 17):

Use:

`myarray.index "valuetoFind"`

That will return you the index of the element you want or nil if your array doesn't contain the value.

Answer (score 10):

This answer is for everyone that realizes the accepted answer does not address the question as it currently written.

The question asks how to **find** a value in an array. The accepted answer shows how to check whether a value **exists** in an array.

There is already an example using `index`, so I am providing an example using the `select` method.

```
1.9.3-p327 :012 > x = [1,2,3,4,5]
  => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
1.9.3-p327 :013 > x.select {|y| y == 1}
  => [1]
```

Comment: @MarkThomas please quote the part of my answer that you're claiming is an incorrect statement and I'll gladly update it. I'm assuming we're using English here (not made up definitions for words). And when thousands of people search "ruby FIND value in array" in Google they are seeing this question as the first result, so I'm sure they would all love to actually get the correct answer.

Comment: Furthermore, @MarkThomas if you were correct then this question should be closed for being duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986386/check-if-value-exists-in-array-in-ruby, but there is a functional difference between "finding" and "checking for existence" in an array.

Comment: I'm allergic to folks resurrecting old questions and providing little to no more substance. This happens a lot. In your case, although `select` was already provided as an answer in 2009, you did provide a sample snippet which is a little better. So after rethinking it, I retract what I said earlier.

Answer (score 8):

I know this question has already been answered, but I came here looking for a way to filter elements in an Array based on some criteria. So here is my solution example: using `select`, I find all constants in Class that start with "RUBY_"

```
Class.constants.select {|c| c.to_s =~ /^RUBY_/ }
```

**UPDATE:** In the meantime I have discovered that Array#grep works much better. For the above example,

```
Class.constants.grep /^RUBY_/
```

did the trick.

Comment: In the meantime I have discovered that Array#grep works much better. Even for the above example, `Class.constants.grep /^RUBY_/` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can go for array methods.

To see all array methods use `methods` function with array.
For Example,

```
a = ["name", "surname"] 
a.methods
```

By the way you can use different method for checking value in array
You can use `a.include?("name")`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for replies.

I did like this:

```
puts 'find' if array.include?(value)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
let arr = [
    { name:"string 1", value:"this", other: "that" },
    { name:"string 2", value:"this", other: "that" }
];

let h = arr.find(x => x.name == 'string 1') ?? arr[0]

console.log(h);
```

Comment: This isn't ruby, it's javascript!