# How would I check if a value is found in an array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to perform an if condition where, if `linkedpub.LPU_ID` is found in an array of values(`@associated_linked_pub`), do some action.

I tried the following but the syntax is not correct.

Any suggestion is most welcomed..Thanks a lot

```
<% for linkedpub in Linkedpub.find(:all) %>
   <% if linkedpub.LPU_ID IN @associated_linked_pub  %>
       # do action
   <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if value exists in array in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986386/check-if-value-exists-in-array-in-ruby)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `Array#include?`

So...

```
if @associated_linked_pub.include? linkedpub.LPU_ID
  ...
```

**Edit**:

If `@associated_linked_pub` is a list of ActiveRecord objects then try this instead:

```
if @associated_linked_pub.map{|a| a.id}.include? linkedpub.LPU_ID
  ...
```

**Edit**:

Looking at your question in more detail, it looks like what you are doing is VERY inefficient and unscalable. Instead you could do...

For Rails 3.0:

```
Linkedpub.where(:id => @associated_linked_pub)
```

For Rails 2.x:

```
LinkedPub.find(:all, :conditions => { :id => @associated_linked_pub })
```

Rails will automatically create a SQL IN query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM linkedpubs WHERE id IN (34, 6, 2, 67, 8)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
linkedpub.LPU_ID.in?(@associated_linked_pub.collect(&:id))
```

Using `in?` in these cases has always felt more natural to me.

Comment: Can you provide document link?

Answer (score 1):

```
@associated_linked_pub.collect(&:id).include?(linkedpub.LPU_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

if `@associated_linked_pub` is an array, try

```
if @associated_linked_pub.include?(linkedpub.LPU_ID)
```