# Is there an inverse 'member?' method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I often find myself checking if some value belongs to some set. As I understand, people normally use `Enumerable#member?` for this.

```
end_index = ['.', ','].member?(word[-1]) ? -3 : -2
```

However, this feels a little less elegant than most of things in Ruby. I'd rather write this code as

```
end_index = word[-1].is_in?('.', ',') ? -3 : -2
```

but I fail to find such method. Does it even exist? If not, any ideas as to why?

Comment: You also can use alias for member? method: include?. This may look better in your context: ['.', ','].include?(word[-1]).

Comment: @Alex thanks, I almost forgot about it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10601055/8279

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not in ruby but [in ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion.rb):

```
characters = ["Konata", "Kagami", "Tsukasa"]
"Konata".in?(characters) # => true
```

Answer (score 10):

You can easily define it along this line:

```
class Object
  def is_in? set
    set.include? self
  end
end
```

and then use as

```
8.is_in? [0, 9, 15]   # false
8.is_in? [0, 8, 15]   # true
```

or define

```
class Object
  def is_in? *set
    set.include? self
  end
end
```

and use as

```
8.is_in?(0, 9, 15)   # false
8.is_in?(0, 8, 15)   # true
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew I could. But I'd rather not drag this code to every new project. :-)

Comment: @Sergei Tulentsev: The choice is yours.

Comment: Just put it in a gem or something, then.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer for your question, but perhaps a solution for your problem.

`word` is a String, isn't it?

You may check with a regex:

```
end_index = word =~ /\A[\.,]/  ? -3 : -2
```

or

```
end_index = word.match(/\A[\.,]/)  ? -3 : -2
```

Comment: Yeah, that would solve this exact problem, but there are many others, like [:admin, :moderator].include?(current_user.role)

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case there's [end_with?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F), which takes multiple arguments.

```
"Hello.".end_with?(',', '.') #=> true
```

Comment: The question was about general case, I just pasted the latest occurence in code. But thanks for the tip, I didn't know about this method.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are dealing with elements that have special meaning for `===` like modules, regexes, etc., you can do pretty much well with `case`.

```
end_index = case word[-1]; when '.', ','; -3 else -2 end
```