# Why is it "array.include? object" and not "object.in? array"?

Tags: python, ruby, arrays, coding-style

I recently discovered that in Python, you can do this:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
if 3 in array:
  print("Yep!")
```

Then, I thought to myself: "Mh, why is it different in Ruby? `if 3 in array` is more readable than `if array.include? 3`." Then, I realized, that Ruby is pure OOP and this approach is keyword-based.

But still, I am wondering. If the Python approach is not OOP, why can't there be another, shorter way in Ruby that is even more readable? When thinking, I don't think "Does this list include that element?", but "Is this element in that list?".

Let's assume, the following code was possible:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

if 3.in? array
  print "Yep!
end
```

I see that it is a turn-around from `list.method(element)` to `element.method(list)`. 
So, I am wondering: *Which ruby principles/rules speak against the above-metioned code?*

**EDIT:** Oops, I wrote "keyboard-based" but meant of course "keyword-based". To emphasize this: I am not looking for methods that behave like the in? method; I am looking for reasons why it is not implemented in Ruby that way.

Comment: I asked this question once! :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/8133397/125816

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, you know, "keyboard-based" as opposed to "mouse-based".

Comment: Just to be clear, whether you prefer the Python approach or the Ruby approach here isn't about whether "the Python approach is not OOP", whatever that means.  Whether a language has a certain syntax to hook into a method of the right hand side object -- such as `__contains__` -- has nothing to do with being more or less object-oriented.

Comment: I don't think your second code would be possible in any sense. You cannot end a script in the middle of a string literal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Which ruby principles/rules speak against the above-metioned code?

It's not a Ruby principle, but rather the general OOP principle of encapsulation: the Fixnum class should not need to know anything about arrays.  However, because Array's primary responsibility is to contain collections of objects, `#in?` or `#include?` clearly falls under Array's responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

In rails (active_support) there is a helper `in?`, which works exactly like you want

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

3.in?([1, 2, 3]) # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

From an OO point of view, this makes sense as `include?` is a method of `Array`, as opposed to being a method of everything else (or `Object`).

The Python variant looks like it is simply a form of [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

Comment: Yes re the sugar: `a in b` is actually `b.__contains__(a)` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Your last sentence explains the problem you're seeing: You're thinking you should be able to ask an object if it exists in an array, which makes no sense. How would it know how to search an array, or array-like object.

Turning it around makes sense: "Does this array contain the object". The array, or array-like object knows how to search itself, and can try comparing the object to the elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

(I have zero Python experience, so I am merely relaying what I read on the internet.)

`in` is an operator in Python, not a method.

> Python has membership operators, which test for membership in a
>   sequence, such as strings, lists, or tuples. There are two membership
>   operators explained below:
>
> **`in`** Evaluates to true if it finds a variable in the specified sequence
>   and false otherwise.
>
> **`not in`** Evaluates to true if it does not finds a variable in the
>   specified sequence and false otherwise.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

I am a Ruby novice; I do not know of any Ruby principles that would discourage writing the object before the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think Mark best answers your question, and for your purpose, `case` statement has the effect of reversing the relation unless you are dealing with elements like module, regex, etc.:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

case 3; when *array
  do_something
end
```

Comment: wow, will this realy work?
AFAIK, ruby's `when` operator tests operands with `===`. But...  What is happening here exactly?

Comment: suddenly, I understood!
when *array means just when 1, 2, 3, 4. 
* is an unpacking operator