# Will my "in?" monkey patch cause issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching

So a fairly common pattern I've run up against is something like this:

```
[:offer, :message].include? message.message_type
```

The inversion of wording there messes me up. So I wrote this little monkey patch for `Symbol` in specific.

```
def in? *scope
  scope.include? self
end
```

So now I can do the previous this way:

```
message.message_type.in? :offer, :message
```

This works fine and I'm happy with it, but occasionally I need similar functionality for other objects. Model objects in Rails apps being the most common case but strings occasionally, etc.

What kind of issues would I run into if I monkey patched this directly into `Object`?

Comment: Rails actually includes method with this exact name, `.in?`

Comment: I looked but never found anything like this. Could you link the documentation?

Comment: Patching `Object` or `Symbol` seems like you're asking for trouble, especially with such a short name.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-in-3F

Comment: @tadman: activesupport gets away with it. :)

Comment: It was one of my first questions on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133397/is-there-an-inverse-member-method-in-ruby

Comment: Interestingly enough, my implementation has been deprecated. I'd be curious to know why.

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate then.

Answer (score 2):

Rails (ActiveSupport) already patches Object with this method. Here is the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-in-3F.

> Returns true if this object is included in the argument. Argument must be any object which responds to #include?. Usage:

```
characters = ["Konata", "Kagami", "Tsukasa"]
"Konata".in?(characters) # => true
```

> This will throw an ArgumentError if the argument doesn’t respond to #include?.

Comment: I approve of the Lucky Star reference incidentally.