# evaluate if array has any items in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a better way to declare this?

```
if current_user.received_replies.unread.count > 0
```

What I'm trying to do is match condition only if there's at least one `unread` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unless current_user.received_replies.unread.empty?
  # ...
end
```

Or, if your `if` has an `else`, switch the cases (because `unless/else` is fugly as hell):

```
if current_user.received_replies.unread.empty?
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use:

```
if current_user.received_replies.unread.any?
```

From the docs:

```
= Array.any?

(from ruby core)
=== Implementation from Enumerable
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  enum.any? [{|obj| block } ]   -> true or false

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method returns
true if the block ever returns a value other than false or nil. If the block
is not given, Ruby adds an implicit block of {|obj| obj} (that is any? will
return true if at least one of the collection members is not false or nil.

       %w{ant bear cat}.any? {|word| word.length >= 3}   #=> true
       %w{ant bear cat}.any? {|word| word.length >= 4}   #=> true
       [ nil, true, 99 ].any?                            #=> true
```

Comment: That is not quite equivalent if the list contains falsy items. In the domain of `ActiveRecord` it might be viable, but I've seen a lot confusion about this where people thought it was just the negation of `empty?`, which is not true in general.

Comment: @NiklasB. Wow I never noticed that. Kind of nasty that `[false].any?` is `false`.

Comment: @Andrew: Why wouldn't it be? Usually this function is to check if a predicate holds for *any* of the items, like in `[1,2,3].any? { |x| x > 2 }`. It's kind of unfortunate that it also works without a block (I don't see where it would be useful).

Comment: @NiklasB. Well that's my point, the version without a block is misleading and doesn't immediately seem to convey its check for truthyness. I agree that it shouldn't exist.

Comment: I find the non-block version quite useful, but then I know that my array will contain truthy elements. If you don't know what is in your array the block is great to provide deeper inspection of the elements. If I have a array of unknown element types, I think I have a bigger problem than whether `any?` works without a block.

Comment: @theTinMan: Sure, I just think if you use it with the purpose of checking if a collection is non-empty, `!x.empty?` is more direct. After all, the `x.any?` version is confusing to both those people who know about the "real" purpose of `any?` (which is only sensible if a block is involved) and those who don't know about it and conclude that `any?` must be the negation of `empty?`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a little bit better :

```
unless current_user.received_replies.unread.empty?
```