# Ruby: Is there an opposite of include? for Ruby Arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got the following logic in my code:

```
if !@players.include?(p.name)
  ...
end
```

`@players` is an array.  Is there a method so I can avoid the `!`?

Ideally, this snippet would be:

```
if @players.does_not_include?(p.name)
  ...
end
```

Comment: is the `do` valid ruby? i get an error `syntax error, unexpected end-of-input` (works if i remove the `do`)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60404934/128421 for benchmarks for searching an array vs. a set.

Answer (score 440, accepted):

```
if @players.exclude?(p.name)
    ...
end
```

ActiveSupport adds the [`exclude?`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/exclude%3F) method to `Array`, `Hash`, and `String`.  This is not pure Ruby, but is used by a LOT of rubyists.

Source: [Active Support Core Extensions (Rails Guides)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#exclude-questionmark)

Comment: [Documentation here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-exclude-3F)

Comment: Minor remark: AS adds it to Enumerable so you can use it with all classes which include Enumerable. Even with Hash. :)

Comment: This is should be green ticked

Comment: The method is no longer auto-loaded in Rails 4.2.3 (and possibly earlier), you'll need to `require 'active_support/core_ext/enumerable'`

Answer (score 109):

Here you go:

```
unless @players.include?(p.name)
  ...
end
```

You might have a look at the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) for more info on similar techniques.

Comment: Upvote for the style guide. Just the reading material I needed.

Comment: readable for one statement. if many then better use negate ! or add your own method to ruby array class.

Comment: Prefer this to the exclude? answer as it's pure Ruby.

Comment: But still weird when working with a compound condition. `if flag unless @players.include?(p.name)` is awkward and `if flag && !@players.include?(p.name)` uses negation.

Comment: While `if` let only `true` pass the condition, `unless` lets pass `false` and `nil`. This sometimes lead to hard to find bugs. Therefore I prefer `exclude?`

Comment: Always pick `if` over `unless`

Answer (score 19):

Looking at Ruby only:

**TL;DR**

Use `none?` passing it a block with `==` for the comparison:

```
[1, 2].include?(1)
  #=> true
[1, 2].none? { |n| 1 == n  }
  #=> false
```

---

[`Array#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) accepts one argument and uses `==` to check against each element in the array:

```
player = [1, 2, 3]
player.include?(1)
 #=> true
```

[`Enumerable#none?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F) can also accept one argument in which case it uses `===` for the comparison. To get the opposing behaviour to `include?` we omit the parameter and pass it a block using `==` for the comparison.

```
player.none? { |n| 7 == n }
 #=> true 
!player.include?(7)    #notice the '!'
 #=> true
```

In the above example we can actually use:

```
player.none?(7)
 #=> true
```

That's because `Integer#==` and `Integer#===` are equivalent. But consider:

```
player.include?(Integer)
 #=> false
player.none?(Integer)
 #=> false
```

`none?` returns `false` because `Integer === 1 #=> true`. But really a legit `notinclude?` method should return `true`. So as we did before:

```
player.none? { |e| Integer == e  }
 #=> true
```

Answer (score 13):

How about the following:

```
unless @players.include?(p.name)
  ....
end
```

Comment: Man, with the speed that answers come in on this site, i don't know if i'll get any reputation without some good-ole nepotism! :-D  The Style Guide link is a nice touch.

Comment: It's not about being fast. It's about being thorough. (I've found) =)

Answer (score 8):

```
module Enumerable
  def does_not_include?(item)
    !include?(item)
  end
end
```

Ok, but seriously, the unless works fine.

Comment: +1 `unless` it's ok for the snippet showed, but the condition may be more complex. I think it's handy to have these negated methods, they allow more declarative code.

Answer (score 8):

If your objection to the `!`-operator is primarily that it needs to be put in front of your check and this breaks your typing flow, then there is the `.!` method. You just put it after the check to invert the boolean:

```
if @players.include?(p.name).!
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `unless`:

```
unless @players.include?(p.name) do
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it's pure Ruby so there's no need to add any peripheral frameworks

```
if @players.include?(p.name) == false do 
  ...
end
```

I was struggling with a similar logic for a few days, and after checking several forums and Q&A boards to little avail it turns out the solution was actually pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use:

```
unless @players.include?(p.name) do
...
end
```

`unless` is opposite of `if`, or you may use `reject`.

You can `reject` the not-required elements:

```
@players.reject{|x| x==p.name}
```

after the getting the results you can do your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Using `unless` is fine for statements with single `include?` clauses but, for example, when you need to check the inclusion of something in one `Array` but not in another, the use of `include?` with `exclude?` is much friendlier.

```
if @players.include? && @spectators.exclude? do
  ....
end
```

But as dizzy42 says above, the use of `exclude?` requires ActiveSupport

Comment: It just needs the use of Active Support's Core Extensions. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/active_support_core_extensions.html#exclude

Answer (score 1):

I was looking up on this for myself, found this, and then a solution. People are using confusing methods and some methods that don't work in certain situations or not at all.

I know it's too late now, considering this was posted 6 years ago, but hopefully future visitors find this (and hopefully, it can clean up their, and your, code.)

Simple solution:

```
if not @players.include?(p.name) do
  ....
end
```

Comment: I don't like it in this context but I'm genuinely surprised that you can use `not` to substitute `!`. Been using Ruby for 15 years and that's new to me. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@players.include?(p.name) ? false : true
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a single method, but chaining `count` and `zero` works:

```
[1, 2, 3].count(1).zero? # => false
[1, 2, 3].count(4).zero? # => true
```

It also works with strings:

```
"hello".count("l").zero? # => false
"hello".count("q").zero? # => true
```