# Is there a ruby function to check whether a number is in an array?

Tags: ruby

Is there a ruby function to check whether a number is in an array?

something like:

```
some_number in?(array)
```

Comment: Pardon what may seem like an insulting suggestion, but did you read the documentation or research this question at all before asking?

Comment: @Phrogz with a name like "RoRLoL", I don't think so.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the downvotes. This question is reasonable and hopefully my answer will be deemed intersting enough to convince others.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune If the question asker had indicated an awareness of Array#include? , and wanted to know if it's possible to have `some_number` before `array` instead, then I would have voted differently.

Comment: The first three results in a Google search for "ruby check number in array" show previous questions for the same thing on SO, and the fourth result is the Ruby API (YMMV)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: The ultimate reasoning behind a downvote is "This question is unclear or not useful". This is not the case. Awareness of possible answers is good but not mandatory in my book.

Comment: @Pavling: Indeed, there seems to be duplicates. An even stronger case for not downgrading the question but closing it instead!

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if value exists in array in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986386/check-if-value-exists-in-array-in-ruby)

Comment: "not useful" would include diluting the question-base on SO by posting duplicates... so a downgrade does apply. If only as an incentive to the OP to delete the question to get their reputation points back, which would be better for SO than having it here for posterity with "closed" stamped on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `in` operator or `#in?` method, but it has been proposed before, [in particular by Yusuke Endoh](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3845) a top notch member of ruby-core.

As pointed out by others, the reverse method [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) exists, for all `Enumerable`s including `Array`, `Hash`, `Set`, `Range`:

```
[1, 2, 3].include?(42) # => false
```

Note that if you have many values in your array, they will all be checked one after the other (i.e. `O(n)`), while that lookup for a hash will be constant time (i.e `O(1)`). So if you array is constant, for example, it is a good idea to use a `Set` instead. E.g:

```
require 'set'
ALLOWED_METHODS = Set[:to_s, :to_i, :upcase, :downcase
                       # etc
                     ]

def foo(what)
  raise "Not allowed" unless ALLOWED_METHODS.include?(what.to_sym)
  bar.send(what)
end
```

A [quick test](http://pastie.org/3913273) reveals that calling `include?` on a 10 element `Set` is about 3.5x faster  than calling it on the equivalent `Array` (if the element is not found).

A final closing note: be wary when using `include?` on a `Range`, there are subtleties, so refer to [the doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) and compare with [`cover?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F)...

Answer (score 7):

Array#[include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F)

```
my_array.include? 25
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) method on an array.

An example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].include?(4)

=> true
```