# Check if array element appears on line

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, contains

I'm going through a file line by line and I want to check if that line contains any element from an array. for instance if I have:

```
myArray = ["cat", "dog", "fish"]
```

and the current line said:

> I love my pet dog

The output would say

> Found a line containing array string

Here's what I have but it doesn't work.

```
myArray = ["cat", "dog", "fish"]
File.open('file.txt').each_line { |line|
  puts "Found a line containing array string" if line =~ myArray  #need to fix this logic
}
```

I've tried `include?` and `any?` but don't know if I'm using them right.

UPDATE:: 
An important part i left out. I need exact matches! so i don't want the statement to return true if it isn't exact. For instance- if my line says "I love my pet doggie" this statement should return false since "dog" is in the array. Not "Doggie"

My mistake on the poor clarification

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986386/check-if-value-exists-in-array-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check each string in the array separately, and use `\b` to match word boundaries to ensure you only get whole words:

```
strings = ["cat", "dog", "fish"].map { |s| Regexp.quote(s) }

File.open('file.txt').each_line do |line|
  strings.each do |string|
    puts "Found a line containing array string" if line =~ /\b#{string}\b/
  end
end
```

Alternatively build a Regex:

```
strings = ["cat", "dog", "fish"].map { |s| Regexp.quote(s) }
pattern = /\b(#{strings.join('|')})\b/

File.open('file.txt').each_line do |line|
  puts "Found a line containing array string" if line =~ pattern
end
```

Calling `Regexp.quote` prevents characters that have meaning in regular expressions from having an unexpected effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a regex using your array

```
myArray = ["cat", "dog", "fish"]
File.open('file.txt').each_line { |line|
  puts "Found a line containing array string" if %r(#{myArray.join('|')}) === line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']

File.open('file.txt').each_line do |line|
  puts 'Found a line containing key word' if arr.any? { |e| line.include? e }
end
```

For detecting as word not as substring:

`line =~ /(#{e}|.*\s#{e})([\s.,:;-].*|\n)/`

Also there is an interesting solution:

```
arr = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']

File.open('file.txt').each_line do |line|
  puts 'Found a line containing array string' if !(line.split(/[\s,.:;-]/) & arr).empty?
end
```

Comment: I think i tried this before and ran into this problem --
I want to match exact words. So if my line said "I love my pet doggie" wouldn't this still return true?  Any idea's on how to modify this for an exact match?

Comment: @JaronBradley You don't mention that in your question. You should update it to include that as that change invalidates every answer here.

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray = ["cat", "dog", "fish"]
File.open('file.txt').each_line { |line|
  puts "Found a line containing array string" if myArray.any? { |word| /.*#{word}.*/.match? line}
}
```

Code not tested