# - if request.fullpath != "/" || "/info" ignores second link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, haml

Sorry for the badly worded title, I currently have this if statement:

```
- if request.fullpath == "/" || "/info"
```

Which works fine, but the other one, that should do the opposite, ignores the second address.

```
- if request.fullpath != "/" || "/info"
```

It acts as if it just says:

```
- if request.fullpath != "/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait a minute, you are using ruby:

```
- if %w(/ /info).include? request.fullpath
#and opposite
- unless %w(/ /info).include? request.fullpath
```

[Check if a value exists in an array in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986386/check-if-value-exists-in-array-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

Or with Rails `String in?` method :

```
- unless request.fullpath.in?("/", "/info")
```

or

```
- if !request.fullpath.in?("/", "/info")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- if request.fullpath != "/" || request.fullpath != "/info"
```

the part on the right is evaluated independantly of the equality test on the left

Comment: I've tried that and i get this error: `syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end`

Comment: this is a wrong condition it will run for every case. their is no significance of this line

Answer (score 0):

try

```
unless request.fullpath != "/" && "/info"
```