# Checking if any element of an array satisfies a condition

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [check if value exists in array in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986386/check-if-value-exists-in-array-in-ruby)

I have this method which loops through an array of strings and returns true if any string contains the string 'dog'.  It is working, but the multiple return statements look messy.  Is there a more eloquent way of doing this?

```
def has_dog?(acct)
  [acct.title, acct.description, acct.tag].each do |text|
    return true if text.include?("dog")
  end
  return false
end
```

Comment: I think that other question only checks to see if one of the array elements `== "dog"` which is distinct from any of the array elements containing that string.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

```
def has_dog?(acct)
  [acct.title, acct.description, acct.tag].any? { |text| text.include? "dog" }
end
```

It will return `true`/`false`.

Comment: Ah, yes, semantically better than `detect`.