# if VARIABLE in ARRAY ruby

Tags: ruby

I thought this should work:

```
def setMethod(method)
  if method in @@methods
    ... do something
  end
end
```

But I keep getting keyword error for `in`

Comment: You get an error because that's not how you check inclusion in Ruby. The error message is telling you true: there is no keyword `in` in Ruby. Use `@@methods.include? method` instead. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986386/check-if-value-exists-in-array-in-ruby. Sometimes the way we expect a language should work isn't the way it works. ;)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was just looking at python code and converting it to ruby and coffeescript has the `in` keyword and claims to try to 'give ease to ruby developers who want to write coffeescript'

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, that's probably a little misleading on their part.

Comment: Ruby does have an `in` keyword that can be used for `for` loops, but it is hardly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, assuming `@@methods` is an array:

```
if @@methods.include?(method)
  # ...
end
```

Comment: The question wasn't clear but they might have wanted this... `for method in @@methods` or better yet `@@methods.each do |method|`

Comment: No it's an if statement just like with python