# Idiomatic way to reject Ruby array elements by their index

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given a Ruby array `ary1`, I'd like to produce another array `ary2` that has the same elements as `ary1`, except for those at a given set of `ary1` indices.

I can monkey-patch this functionality onto Ruby's `Array` class with

```
class Array
  def reject_at(*indices)
    copy = Array.new(self)
    indices.uniq.sort.reverse_each do |i|
      copy.delete_at i
    end
    return copy
  end
end
```

which I can then use like this:

```
ary1 = [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]
ary2 = ary1.reject_at(2, 4)
puts(ary2.to_s) # [:a, :b, :d]
```

While this works fine, I have the feeling that I must be missing something obvious. **Is there some functionality like this already built into Ruby?** E.g., can and should `Array#slice` be used for this task?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't think there is an inbuilt solution for this. Came up with the following:

```
ary1 = [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]
indexes_to_reject = [1,2,3]

ary1.reject.each_with_index{|i, ix| indexes_to_reject.include? ix }
```

Comment: Ah, nice! This answer helped me to finally understand [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerator.html) chaining.

Answer (score 2):

For the opposite, there is [`Array#values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-values_at). You can use that by inverting the indices to select:

```
class Array
  def values_without(*indices)
    values_at(*((0...size).to_a - indices))
  end
end

[:a, :b, :c, :d, :e].values_without(2, 4)
# => [:a, :b, :d]
```

Comment: `values_at(*((0...size).to_a - indices))` can be written as `self - self.values_at(indices)`....

Comment: No. `Array#-` is set difference, not array difference. If there are duplicate elements, that won't work.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Got you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reject.with_index`.

```
ary1 = [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]

ary1.reject.with_index { _2.in?([2,4]) }
=> [:a, :b, :d]
```

Comment: Using the [`with_index` Enumerator](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/with_index) is very elegant! The [`in?` method](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/in%3F) though [is in `ActiveSupport` (part of Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10601055/674064), so in plain Ruby this won't work without additional dependencies. However `ary1.reject.with_index { [2,4].include? _2 }` can be used instead. Do you want to [edit] your question to include that?