# How to properly check if a variable is in array using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to check if variable is in array so I used a solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986386/check-if-a-value-exists-in-an-array-in-ruby/1986398).

The code below works fine if I pass value of tea direct in the include function as per below.

```
mycheck= ['Soap', 'Tea', 'Sugar'].include? 'Tea'
      if mycheck == true
        print("yes present")
      else
        print("not present")
      end
```

**My issues:**
My issue if I set value tea to a variable as per code below, it returns false

```
var_tea = 'Tea'
mycheck= ['Soap', 'Tea', 'Sugar'].include? var_tea
      if mycheck == true
        print("yes present")
      else
        print("not present")
      end
```

Is there any other alternative way like using `is_array()`, etc?

Comment: Your code is working fine, it's not the issue it may be something else. please cross check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried these two lines

```
var_tea = 'Tea'
mycheck = ['Soap', 'Tea', 'Sugar'].include? var_tea
```

and `mycheck` is `true`

My guess is that you obviously don't have that variable in the line above, it's probably coming from a request, and that's not exactly `Tea`, maybe `tea`. Try to print `var_tea` before that check.

```
puts var_tea.inspect
```

Comment: my pleasure @NancyMooree :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right, but you could make it better.

First of all, you're checking if a variable is true. A better way to do it in ruby would be:

```rb
if mycheck
  print("yes present")
else
  print("not present")
end
```

You can also try:

```rb
my_check = var_tea.in? ['Soap', 'Tea', 'Sugar']
```

If you have the same issue, make sure that you double check your code, and that you don't have any `my_check=` method or something.