# Exclude repetition for number 1 in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having array where values could be only `1` or `0`.

```
array_example = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

As you can see there is already `1` in the array, so i need to forbid the case when there could be 2 or more elements with value `1`.

Just as example, in array should be only 1 element with value `1`, so if array will be like this, i should get an error.

```
array_example = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Ruby 1.8.7

Rails 2.3.4

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html

Comment: Set is collecting and ignoring duplicates, but i need to check value `1` on duplicates only.

Comment: `array_example.select{ |element| element == 1 }.size > 1` or do I not understand your question?

Comment: `array_example << 1 unless array_example.include?(1)` More at https://stackoverflow.com/q/1986386/3784008.

Comment: Do you want `[123] << 4` to operate normally but `[1,2,3] << 2` to raise an exception?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend updating your Ruby. 1.8.7 is extremely out of date.

Comment: Since you're using Rails: `array_example.many? { |n| n == 1 }` returns `true` if there's more than one `1` in the array.

Comment: @Stefan I think `array_example.count(1) > 1` probably wins the prize for succinctness, since it doesn't require a block.

Comment: @CarySwoveland OP says values can only be `1` or `0`?

Comment: @BobRodes it's shorter, but `count` always traverses the whole array whereas `many?` stops as soon as it finds a second match.

Comment: @Stefan Good to know, Thanks! I know Ruby quite well, and Rails not at all at present, and thinking about how to get the same functionality in straight Ruby I can see where a method like `many?` would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your explanation could use more clarity, I believe you are saying that you have an array of any number of zeros and zero or one `1`. And, if a `1` gets added to an array already containing one, to raise an error.

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, it isn't difficult. All you have to do is select all the elements that equal `1` and raise an error if the size of the result is greater than `1`:

```
raise 'Too many ones' if array_example.select { |e| 1 == e }.size > 1
```

This will raise the default `RuntimeError`. Of course, you can raise any sort of custom error that you like (and you probably should create a custom one for this if you're going to handle it using `rescue`).

Edit: Cary's suggestion of `Array#count` is indeed more direct. So:

```
raise 'Too many ones' if array_example.count(1) > 1
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes it is. I thought it wasn't available till 1.9; should have looked it up.