# Iterate over array of objects. Then access object method if correct one is found. Otherwise create a new object in the array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I start with an empty array, and a Hash of key, values.

I would like to iterate over the Hash and compare it against the empty array. If the value for each k,v pair doesn't already exist in the array, I would like to create an object with that value and then access an object method to append the key to an array inside the object.

This is my code

```
class Test

   def initialize(name)
     @name = name
     @values = []
   end

   attr_accessor :name

   def values=(value)
     @values << value
   end

   def add(value)
     @values.push(value)
   end


end

l = []

n = {'server_1': 'cluster_x', 'server_2': 'cluster_y', 'server_3': 'cluster_z', 'server_4': 'cluster_x', 'server_5': 'cluster_y'}

n.each do |key, value|
  l.any? do |a|
    if a.name == value
      a.add(key)
    else
      t = Test.new(value)
      t.add(key)
      l << t
    end
  end
end

p l
```

I would expect to see this:

```
[
#<Test:0x007ff8d10cd3a8 @name=:cluster_x, @values=["server_1, server_4"]>, 
#<Test:0x007ff8d10cd2e0 @name=:cluster_y, @values=["server_2, server_5"]>, 
#<Test:0x007ff8d10cd1f0 @name=:cluster_z, @values=["server_3"]>
]
```

Instead I just get an empty array.

I think that the condition `if a.name == value` is not being met and then the add method isn't being called.

Comment: `l.any?` will always be false since you are never adding anything to it.

Comment: Might also want to take a look at `group_by`, might or might not help you here: `n.group_by { |_, v| v }` or `n.keys.group_by { |key| n[key] }`

Answer (score 1):

@Cyzanfar gave me a clue as to what to look for, and I found the answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34904864/5006720

```
n.each do |key, value|
    found = l.detect {|e| e.name == value}
    if found
      found.add(key)
    else
      t = Test.new(value)
      t.add(key)
      l << t
    end
end
```

Comment: Nice job! The only issue I see here is your last line `l << t` that will cause `nil` value to be added to the array since everytime a `found` returns an actual object, the variable `t` will not be set.

Comment: @cyzanfar Absolutely right, I just noticed that too. Many thanks for your advice!

Comment: Oh awesome :) just added an answer, didn't see your last comment :). And +1 for finding your mistake!

Answer (score 0):

@ARL you're almost there! The last thing you need to consider is when `found` actually returns an object since `detect` will find a matching one at some point.

```
 n.each do |key, value|
    found = l.detect {|e| e.name == value}
    if found
      found.add(key)
    else
      t = Test.new(value)
      t.add(key)
      l << t
    end
end
```

You actually only want to add a new instance of `Test` when `found` return `nil`. This code should yield your desired output:

```
[
#<Test:0x007ff8d10cd3a8 @name=:cluster_x, @values=["server_1, server_4"]>, 
#<Test:0x007ff8d10cd2e0 @name=:cluster_y, @values=["server_2, server_5"]>, 
#<Test:0x007ff8d10cd1f0 @name=:cluster_z, @values=["server_3"]>
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I observe two things in your code :

```
   def values=(value)
     @values << value

   def add(value)
     @values.push(value)
```

- two methods do the same thing, pushing a value, as `<<` is a kind of syntactic sugar meaning push
- you have changed the meaning of `values=`, which is usually reserved for a setter method, equivalent to `attire_writer :values`.

Just to illustrate that there are many ways to do things in Ruby, I propose the following :

```
class Test
  def initialize(name, value)
    @name   = name
    @values = [value]
  end

  def add(value)
    @values << value
  end
end

h_cluster = {} # intermediate hash whose key is the cluster name

n = {'server_1': 'cluster_x', 'server_2': 'cluster_y', 'server_3': 'cluster_z',
     'server_4': 'cluster_x', 'server_5': 'cluster_y'}

n.each do | server, cluster |
  puts "server=#{server}, cluster=#{cluster}"
  cluster_found = h_cluster[cluster] # does the key exist ? => nil or Test 
                                     # instance with servers list
  puts "cluster_found=#{cluster_found.inspect}"

  if cluster_found
  then # add server to existing cluster
    cluster_found.add(server)
  else # create a new cluster
    h_cluster[cluster] = Test.new(cluster, server)
  end
end

p h_cluster.collect { | cluster, servers | servers }
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
server=server_1, cluster=cluster_x
cluster_found=nil
server=server_2, cluster=cluster_y
cluster_found=nil
server=server_3, cluster=cluster_z
cluster_found=nil
server=server_4, cluster=cluster_x
cluster_found=#<Test:0x007fa7a619ae10 @name="cluster_x", @values=[:server_1]>
server=server_5, cluster=cluster_y
cluster_found=#<Test:0x007fa7a619ac58 @name="cluster_y", @values=[:server_2]>
[#<Test:0x007fa7a619ae10 @name="cluster_x", @values=[:server_1, :server_4]>,
 #<Test:0x007fa7a619ac58 @name="cluster_y", @values=[:server_2, :server_5]>,
 #<Test:0x007fa7a619aac8 @name="cluster_z", @values=[:server_3]>]
```